# Query for last values from column1 show all rows

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an example table:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
--------+---------+--------
1          Test1   1.1.2021
2          Test1   1.1.2020
1          Test2   2.1.2021
3          Test1   4.1.2021
2          Test2   5.1.2020
1          Test3   6.1.2021
```

I want to get:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
--------+---------+--------
2          Test2    5.1.2020
3          Test1    4.1.2021
1          Test3    6.1.2021
```

Is there a way using the query language?

Such as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1, 
ORDER BY Column4 ASC, DISTINCT Column1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the most recent row -- based on `column3` for each value in `column1`.  If so, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from table1 as t
where t.column3 = (select max(t2.column3)
                   from table1 as t2
                   where t2.column1 = t.column1
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, it works perfectly! How exactly does it work? Did you create two sub tables, t1 & t2? Sadly I do not have enough reputation to upvote your comment...

Comment: @DamnSpaceship . . . This type of subquery is called a *correlated subquery*.  There are many resources on the web where you can learn about the construct.